# vs code with python does not report running syntax errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code some Python running errors do not display an error message, then just end the running of the program.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
s = a.shape()
print(s)
```

Line 3 is an error.  It should be:

```
s = a.shape
```

When running the Python code with the error in VS code, no error message is given, nothing is displayed in the problems, output, debug or terminal windows.  The program just stops.

Suggestions?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and you are getting a `TypeError` => `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. So, on the previous line, whatever you are doing, `a` is now a tuple.

Comment: What's the behavior *outside* of VS Code? The VS Code version might also be relevant. Are you using latest stable?

Comment: @idjaw - The python error is not the issue.  The issue is VS Code is not reporting the error.

Comment: @jpmc26  I am using the latest stable release of VS code 1.14.1

Comment: FWIW running this in PyCharm - using the same code and python libraries returns the error with a valid stack trace.